# Generating sample objects from model

Tags: java

Is there a tool to generate sample objects from a model(pojo)? I was unable to find any, probably using the wrong search terms.

Question in more detail:
I have a model, e.g.(removed getter/setter/constr for better readibility):

```
public class SomeModel {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private AnotherModel anotherModel;
}
public class AnotherModel {
    private String foo;
    private int bar;
}
```

Is there a way to generate objects(or code) to sample fill recursively the model? So the tool or the library does either one of these things:

```
new SomeModel("randomText", "randomText2", new AnotherModel("randomText3", 42))
new SomeModel("randomText4", "randomText5", new AnotherModel("randomText6", 42))
//... as many as I want
new SomeModel("randomTextN", "randomTextN", new AnotherModel("randomTextN", 42))

//or:
MockMyData<SomeModel> mocker = new MockMyData<SomeModel>()
mocker.generate()
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the use case ? :)

Comment: It seems to me you are describing two tools here: Dependency Injection, and Mocking. See [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) for the first and [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) for the second as exmaples. (Or did I completely misunderstood your intent?)

Comment: I am sorry, it seems I didnt make it clear enough. My reason behind this is to generate sample data. So I can use the application. The real datasource is currently not available.
I am currently looking into Mockito, but I dont see the advantage of dependency injection (except swapping the datasource which is not yet available)